# Why SimpleDateFormat in Android does not work?

Tags: android

```
public static String getDateFormatStr(long time,String formatStr){
    String timeStr=null;
    SimpleDateFormat setDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formatStr);
    timeStr = setDateFormat.format(time);
    return timeStr;
}
```

**e.g ：**
HH:mm, E, MMM dd, yyyy

**result：**
11：30, 5,11 08, 2012

**Question:**
Why is not 11:30,Web,Nov 08,2012,, but 11：30, 5, 11 08, 2012?

Comment: Must be whats in `formatString`. Can you show where it came from

Comment: did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code. its simply working good. check this testing

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    long l = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println(getDateFormatStr(l,"HH:mm, E, MMM dd, yyyy"));


}

public static String getDateFormatStr(long time,String formatStr){
    String timeStr=null;
    SimpleDateFormat setDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formatStr);
    timeStr = setDateFormat.format(time);
    return timeStr;
}
```

Result:   **08:49, Mon, Nov 12, 2012**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Calendar class and this sample:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance(); `
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMMMMM");
String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
```

Month name will contain the full month name. If you want short month name use this:

```
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick guess, your phone is set to use an unusual Locale.  Try specifying a specific Locale when you create your SimpleDateFormat, i.e. `new SimpleDateFormat(formatStr, Locale.ENGLISH)`